# How to hide children layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Let's say I have a parent Rectangle layer, and 3 children Circle layers.

[image: Image 1]

What properties do I need to set in order to have the circles be forced within the boundaries of the parent so that when I want to position them inside the Rectangle, they don't leak outside the parent?

[image]

In case it matters, I'm using Photoshop CS6 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the rectangle object by **ctrl/cmd clicking** in the layer window thumbnail.

Go to Layer>Add Layer Mask>Reveal selection

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately when I cmd click the Rectangle shape the Layer Mask option is disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it creating a selection around the rectangle?
essentially thats your end goal, a selection thats the size of the rectangle, then add layer mask.

Comment: Yes, see here: http://i.imgur.com/T4LmMMX.png

Comment: ahhh gotcha, you can group the 3 circles, CTRL/CMD-G, select the group with the rectangle selection and the option should be there.

Comment: Works :) Cheers!